# How to extract specific numbers from a string?

Tags: objective-c, string, extract

probably already talked much about it. Don't be angry. But I can't make this string ends as I want. I've cut using NSMakeRange but this does not help because the days vary and so too my range.

I need to extract: 02 35 of a string like this "[fire date = lunes, 18 de agosto de 2014 02h'35:28 Horas stander de Argentina...."

Edit:

ok, no...

I need to extract: 02 35 of a string like this "`< UIConcreteLocalNotificacion: 0x8e874f0>` [fire date = lunes, 18 de agosto de 2014 02h'35:28 Horas estandar de Argentina"

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.textLabel setText:localNotification.alertBody];

NSString *strdelArray = [[localNotifications valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSString *strdelArrayCortado = [strdelArray substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(53, 37)];

[cell.detailTextLabel setText: strdelArray];
labelParse.text = strdelArrayCortado;

// this show "lunes, 18 de agosto de 2014 02h'35:28"
//try pass string to numbers.. but only see 18

NSString *numberString;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:strdelArrayCortado];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];


[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:NULL];

[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&numberString];

labelParse.text = numberString;
return cell;}"
```

Comment: set dateFormat to `hh mm`

Answer (score 1):

First of all convert your string into date formate :-

```
    fireDateStr = @"lunes, 18 de agosto de 2014 02h'35:28 Horas";  
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ";
    NSDate *dateAndTime = [formatter dateFromString: fireDateStr];
```

then extract your time like this :-

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    [dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];// Set timeZone according to your requirement.

    NSString *newFireDateStr =[dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:dateAndTime];
```